# React Native - What is the difference between StyleSheet.absoluteFill() and StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject()?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, css-position, absolute

The [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet#absolutefill) provided an example for `StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject()` whose behavior is also same while using with `StyleSheet.absoluteFill()`:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  wrapper: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    top: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
});
```

What is the difference between `StyleSheet.absoluteFill()` and `StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject()`? A little example will be more appreciated. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 29):

absoluteFill is an easy way to set a view to be full screen and absolute positioned. It’s a short cut for:

```
{
 position: 'absolute',
 top: 0,
 left: 0,
 bottom: 0,
 right: 0
```

}

Use it to extend your other styles like this:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
   backgroundColor: 'red'
   }
});
<View style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFill, styles.container]} />
```

absoluteFillObject
Say you want to absolute position your view, but bump it down 20px to offset for the status bar (for example).
You can spread StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject into your style and then override one of it’s values.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
   top: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  }
});
<View style={styles.container} />
```

Comment: The thing you mention in the answer for `StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject` can also be done with the `StyleSheet.absoluteFill`, so, what can be the difference?

Comment: According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69968270/3484824 it makes a difference when using TypeScript as you can't spread `StyleSheet.absoluteFill` into a stylesheet, apparently

Answer (score 15):

There is no difference between those two. You can see this in [StyleSheet.js](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js#L266):

> ```
>  /**
>    * A very common pattern is to create overlays with position absolute and zero positioning,
>    * so `absoluteFill` can be used for convenience and to reduce duplication of these repeated
>    * styles.
>    */
>   absoluteFill: (absoluteFill: any), // TODO: This should be updated after we fix downstream Flow sites.
>
>   /**
>    * Sometimes you may want `absoluteFill` but with a couple tweaks - `absoluteFillObject` can be
>    * used to create a customized entry in a `StyleSheet`, e.g.:
>    *
>    *   const styles = StyleSheet.create({
>    *     wrapper: {
>    *       ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
>    *       top: 10,
>    *       backgroundColor: 'transparent',
>    *     },
>    *   });
>    */
>   absoluteFillObject: absoluteFill,
> ```

[image]

Comment: Yes, "Use the Source, Luke"! Here's the reference to check what is the situation in the latest version:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js#L266

Answer (score 7):

I may be late for the party. But there is some difference between `absoluteFill` and `absoluteFillObject` in typescript.

Mainly in typescript, the type of:

- `absoluteFill` is `RegisteredStyle<StyleSheet.AbsoluteFillStyle>`
- `absoluteFillObject` is `StyleSheet.AbsoluteFillStyle`

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        // must use "absoluteFillObject" in typescript
        ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    }
})
```

For JavaScript, there is no difference.

Answer (score 4):

As of version 0.62, no difference at all according to the [official document](https://reactnative.dev/docs/stylesheet#absolutefill-vs-absolutefillobject)

In case you are using EXPO Snack like I do, the `absoluteFill` preview on web seems buggy at this time. On a real device, it should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

[Currently, there is no difference between using `absoluteFill` vs. `absoluteFillObject`.](https://reactnative.dev/docs/stylesheet#absolutefill-vs-absolutefillobject)

Answer (score 2):

Currently (React Native 0.66), the [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/stylesheet#absolutefill-vs-absolutefillobject) states:

> there is no difference between using `absoluteFill` vs. `absoluteFillObject`.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to print the value of `absoluteFill` and `absoluteFillObject`.
They're no difference. They're the same value.

```
[LOG] absoluteFill: {"bottom": 0, "left": 0, "position": "absolute", "right": 0, "top": 0}
[LOG] absoluteFillObject: {"bottom": 0, "left": 0, "position": "absolute", "right": 0, "top": 0}
```